# extern function called with less params

Tags: c, device-driver, extern

I had called an extern function in c by mistake with less params.it crashed in the very next line where we were using an extern offset to do readl. (It did not fail in the function called by mistake)Can somebody help me understand.It was an Arm based board.

Comment: Provide some context for your question.  An example showing relevant sections of code would help. (I did not down vote)

Comment: You may have "called an extern function in c by mistake with less params", but either 1) your did not notice the compiler warning or 2) did not have compiler warning sufficiently enabled.  Suggest fixing _that_.

Answer (score 0):

The function prototype must match with its definition which can be in the same or a different translation unit. If they don't match, then it's ill-formed and invokes undefined behaviour.